# Django template reusability

Tags: django

In our project, we use the bootstrap widget module widely.

```
<div class="widget">
  <header>
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>product-list</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm toggle-widget" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="inner-padding">
    ...............
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget">
  <header>
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        user info
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm toggle-widget" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="inner-padding">
    .............
  </div>
</div>
```

We repeat these code again and again. My problem is that how can I write a template and make these code reusable.

If I make a sub template like this:

```
<div class="widget">
  <header>
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h2><i class="fa {{ icon }}"></i>
        {{ title }}
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm toggle-widget" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="inner-padding">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I can use {% include %} to include the template:

```
{% include "sub-template.html" with icon="..." title="..." %}
```

But how can I render 'block content'?
In addition, we may include this sub-template.html several times in one template:

```
{% include "sub-template.html" with icon="1" title="user-info" %}
{% include "sub-template.html" with icon="2" title="product-list" %}
```

I think this is a very common scenario, but I can not find a solution using Django template. Is there anyone can give me some suggestion?

Comment: What exactly goes in the `block content`?

Comment: @AKS, different things according to the title and the page, which include the sub-template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I could consider a template of `header` only:

```
# header-template.html

<header>
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h2><i class="fa {{ icon }}"></i>
        {{ title }}
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm toggle-widget" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

and, then use it in widgets:

```
<div class="widget">
  {% include "header-template.html" with icon="1" title="user-info" %}
  <div class="inner-padding">
    .............
  </div>
</div>


<div class="widget">
  {% include "header-template.html" with icon="2" title="product-list" %}
  <div class="inner-padding">
    .............
  </div>
</div>
```

If you think that for some of the widgets the content is also common, then you can create a template of that too, and use it in the widget.

Comment: TNX for your answer, it makes sense to me.  Let's wait for a better answer. if no better ones, i will choose your solution.